# Funcion condicional en wordpress no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

Estoy desarrollando una Tienda en Linea en Wordpress con el tema de Storefront y lo que intento hacer es poner un botón flotante, que abra un popup conteniendo un filtro del plugin WOOF, unicamente en las paginas de productos y categorías.

Por lo cual tengo el siguiente código que funciona bien sin embargo no he logrado ponerlo unicamente en las paginas antes mencionadas:

El codigo functions.php es el siguiente --->

```
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    //Cargando script para la apertura del popup
    wp_register_script('custom_jquery', ( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js'), array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');


    //Agregando boton para la apertura del popup en el menu de storefront
    add_filter( 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar_links', 'jk_add_home_link' );
    function jk_add_home_link( $links ) {    
    $new_links = array(
        'filtros' => array(
               'priority' => 10,
               'callback' => 'jk_home_link_2',
                ),
    );    
    $links = array_merge( $new_links, $links );
    return $links;
    }

    // Agregando la estructura HTML para la ventana del popup
    function jk_home_link_2() {    
    echo '<a href="#" id="myBtn"></a>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="stftitle">Filtros</span>
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>'
                     . do_shortcode('[woof]') . 

                '</div>
        </div>';
    }
```

Encontre este hook con este condicional que hace remover el widget lateral de strorefront en todas las paginas menos en productos y categorias, he intentado ponerlo pero sin exito

```
add_action( 'wp', 'woa_remove_sidebar_shop_page' );
function woa_remove_sidebar_shop_page() {
    if (!is_shop() && !is_product_category()) {        

    //Codigo

    }
}
```

Espero que alguien tenga una buena idea, muchas gracias :)

Comment: no seria ese if, pero al reves?

Comment: Si, pero aun así quitando los not. No funciona

Comment: Y como lo intentaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Cargando script para la apertura del popup
add_action( 'wp', 'woofilterhook' );
function woofilterhook() {
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category()) {        
        wp_register_script('js_filtro', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/script_filtro.js', array(), null , true );
        wp_enqueue_script('js_filtro');   

//Agregando boton para la apertura del popup en el menu de storefront
    add_filter( 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar_links', 'jk_add_home_link3' );
    function jk_add_home_link3( $links ) {

        $new_links = array(
            'filtros' => array(
                'priority' => 9,
                'callback' => 'jk_home_link_2',
            ),
        );    
        $links = array_merge( $new_links, $links );
        return $links;
    }

// Agregando la estructura HTML para la ventana del popup
    function jk_home_link_2() {    
        echo '<a href="#" id="myBtn"></a>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="stftitle">Filtros</span>
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>'
                        . do_shortcode('[woof]') . 

                    '</div>
            </div>';
}


    }   

    }
```

Espero a alguien le sirva :)